# Attempting to bind custom control properties to IsEnabled property, but one property not updating

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a custom built numeric entry which includes a stepper. Everything is completely functional except one thing regarding property bindings. IsEnabled and Opacity properties are bound to the increment/decrement buttons. Basically, as long as the 'Value' property is > then Min or < Max, increment or decrement can be tapped.

The only time it doesn't work as intended is when the 'Max' property gets updated instead of 'Value'. In some cases, I have collections of objects where the entry needs to be used as part of input.

Below is some relevant code and properties related to the increment button. Pay close attention to the binding. I am binding to 'Value' but also comparing 'Max' to it... but in reality, the binding only fires if 'Value' changes.

```
public double? Value { get { return (double?)GetValue(ValueProperty); } set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); } }
public static readonly BindableProperty ValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Value), typeof(double?), typeof(Nu), null);

public double? Max { get { return (double?)GetValue(MaxProperty); } set { SetValue(MaxProperty, value); } }
public static readonly BindableProperty MaxProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Max), typeof(double?), typeof(NumericEntry), null);

public event EventHandler Tapped;

new PancakeView (true, 0) // This is tappable, it increments 'Value' by one
{ 
   Content = new FontAwesome
   {
      Text = "\u002b", // Plus Symbol
   }.Bind(OpacityProperty, nameof(Value), source: this, convert: (double? d) => Max == null || (d.HasValue && d.Value < Max) ? 1 : .25)
   .CenterExpand()
}.Bind(IsEnabledProperty, nameof(Value), source: this, convert: (double? d) => Max == null || (d.HasValue && d.Value < Max))
.Invoke(pv => pv.TapEvent += Increment_Tapped)

private void Increment_Tapped(object s, EventArgs e)
{
   PancakeView pv = s as PancakeView;
   OnStepperPress(pv);

   if (Value == null)
   {
      Value = 0;
   }

   if (Value < Max || Max == null)
   {
      Value += 1;
   }

   OnSubmitTap(s, e);
}

private void OnSubmitTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Tapped?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

**UPDATES**

Had to fire `PropertyChanged` within a property-changed callback method in the Bindable Property. See Liqun Shen's answer, that fixed it.

Thanks to @Jason as well, he provided the same solution but I realize now that the reason it wasn't working when I implemented it was because I was not instantiating a `Value` or `Max` on the initial object that was added to relevant ObservableCollection.

Comment: you can raise multiple `PropertyChanged` events in a property's setter.  Or you can use a package like Fody that has `DependsOn` attributes to allow multiple changes to fire

Comment: I tried firing a ```PropertyChanged``` within the setter for both the ```Max``` and ```Value``` properties, ```OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Max))``` and ```OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value))```. When ```Value``` changes, it doesn't fire ```Max``` for whatever reason. I can provide more code in the post if it would help.

Comment: Does each custom entry's IsEnable property bind to the same proeprty in viewmodel? Do you fire the property change for each instance? Could you please share a [minimal,complete, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok added the code from the page that is shown in the picture. I removed as much as I could that is generally irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: I also added a bit more to the code related to the entry I made.

Comment: I have it set to a twoway binding between the main page and the numeric entry. As ```Value``` updates, it works both ways. Bindings seem to be working, but it's possible I could just be missing something and not realize it?

Comment: May I ask what's the code for ```CustomEntry``` and ```NumericEntry```?  What's the difference between them? Need more code to reproduce.

Comment: ```NumericEntry``` is the only entry, sorry. I made changes to reflect that. I also added the relevant code for ```NumericEntry```. I stripped a lot of the formatting code that isn't relevant. Let me know if that helped or if I need to provide more.

Comment: I believe the root of the issue has something to do with the bindings. If you look at the  ```RowCollection_PropertyChanged``` method, I'm reassigning the ```Max``` property for all of the objects, and that change gets reflected in the collection... but no visual changes occur for the binding of the opacity/enabled properties within ```NumericEntry``` unless I change the ```Value``` property of the respective row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updates**

> if there was a way to fire Max and Value at the same time,

I totally agree with you.

`BindableProperty` could 
[Detect property changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties).

So you could add this property-changed callback method for `Max` property.

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty MaxProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Max), typeof(double?), typeof(NumericEntry), null,
        propertyChanged:OnMaxPropertyChanged);

    private static void OnMaxPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        NumericEntry ne = bindable as NumericEntry;
        ne.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
    }
```

When the `Max` property changes, the `Value` property change also fire.

Ignore my origin post.

---

Let's look at the code in `NumericEntry.cs`:

```
Content = new FontAwesome
         {
         Text = "\uf068",
         }.Bind(OpacityProperty, nameof(Value)....
```

In this code, you bind the `OpacityProperty` to the `Value`. And `Value` property is a BindableProperty defined in `NumericEntry.cs`. This `Value` property binds to the `Amount` property in ***Row class***.

**Each NumericEntry binds to one corresponding row in RowCollection.** They are separate.

Now suppose when you add one step for ID2 entry, you only change the `Value` property for ID2 entry. ID1 and ID3's `Value` Property do not change. So their OpacityProperty or IsEnabledProperty will not change.

***Workaround***

The key point is when a property of an entry change, it should notify other entry. I think it's hard to do so based on the existing code structure. So I may try a different way here.

For Row class, I will

1.add two more properties to control the IsEnable for each stepper, such as:

```
private bool isPlusEnabled;
public bool IsPlusEnabled { get => id; set => Set(ref isPlusEnabled, value); }
```

and

```
private bool isMinusEnabled;
public bool IsMinusEnabled { get => isMinusEnabled; set => Set(ref isMinusEnabled, value); }
```

2.Add two more BindableProperty in `NumericEntry.cs`

```
public bool IsPlusEnabled { get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPlusEnabledProperty); } set { SetValue(IsPlusEnabledProperty, value); } }

public static readonly BindableProperty IsPlusEnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsPlusEnabled), typeof(bool), typeof(NumericEntry) );

public bool IsMinusEnabled { get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMinusEnabledProperty); } set { SetValue(IsMinusEnabledProperty, value); } }
public static readonly BindableProperty IsMinusEnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsMinusEnabled), typeof(bool), typeof(NumericEntry) );
```

3.Change some logic in **RowCollection_ItemPropertyChanged**

```
private void RowCollection_ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{


    foreach (Row r in RowCollection)
    {
        ...
        if(r.Amount < r.Max)
        {
            r.IsPlusEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            r.IsPlusEnabled = false;
        }
        if(r.Amount > 0)
        {
            r.IsMinusEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            r.IsMinusEnabled = false;
        }
        ....
    }
```

4.Consume the property

```
.Bind(OpacityProperty, nameof(IsPlusEnabled), source: this, convert:boolToOpacity)
                                                                                     
.Bind(IsEnabledProperty, nameof(IsPlusEnabled), source: this)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I see how your answer can work. I tried doing it but for some reason both -/+ are always disabled. I'll keep messing with it, but with this implementation, it restricts the IsEnabled to only being accessible on this page, and if I want it to be used on other pages and for other classes, I'll have to reuse the same properties every time. Would it be possible to implement it within the ```NumericEntry``` class? That way it's to enforce these rules upon all instances of ```NumericEntry```.

Comment: Also, I definitely understand how my existing code structure makes this whole concept difficult to maintain. Are there alternative ideas or code structures that you can provide to push me in the right direction of making this simpler to implement?

Comment: The real trouble comes in when trying to get all of the ```NumericEntry```'s to realize the other instances are changing, and I guess that's where my code structure gets a bit wonky... although I was under the impression that if there was a way to fire ```Max``` and ```Value``` at the same time, then the comparators would work within the bindings for Opacity & IsEnabled in ```NumericEntry```.

Comment: I've been thinking about this and want to see if taking a completely different approach is more effective. If I wanted to make the property of one entry realize when another entry property changes, what would be a more intuitive alternative to what I came up with? Would I have to make some sort of separate class outside of the main page that I am working on?

Comment: You could add a property-changed callback method for Max property. Please take a look at this doc [Detect property changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#detect-property-changes). When the Max property change, also fire the Value property change. See my updates and ignore my origin post. @chikennuget

Comment: Wow. I swear I implemented ```PropertyChanged``` exactly same way you did when Jason mentioned it a couple days ago, and it hadn't worked at the time. What you sent fixed the issue. Now it will works in all cases and I won't have to create properties outside of the ```NumericEntry```. Thanks a bunch for the insight @Jason @Liqun Shen